How can I change the app display name and app icon build with Flutter?
I want to change the app name. I have created only the front end design. I need to change the name of the mobile app. Also I need to know how to change the app icon. I want to know what the the changes that I should do when I changing the name.
the method how I can change the name

This question is similar to: How can I change the app display name build with Flutter?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As @AnandhKrishnan said for change display name build you can refer this answer and to change app icon here's an Answer.

You need to find better before to ask a new question

To change the app name and icon in a Flutter project, you will need to make updates in the project files and configuration.
>> Changing the App Name
>> Update Android app name:
Open the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file.
Locate the <application> tag and update the android:label attribute:
<application
    android:label="New App Name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    ...
</application>

>> Update iOS app name:
Open the ios/Runner/Info.plist file.
Locate the <key>CFBundleName</key> and update the string value:
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>New App Name</string>

>> Update the app name in the pubspec.yaml file:
Open the pubspec.yaml file and update the name attribute:
name: new_app_name

Changing the App Icon
To change the app icon, you can use a Flutter package like flutter_launcher_icons. This package simplifies the process of generating app icons for both Android and iOS.
Add flutter_launcher_icons to pubspec.yaml:
